# How to fix gyp ERR! inside a npm build

Tags: docker, npm, node-gyp, node-pre-gyp

I recently built a mean stack app and containerized it. However, I have trouble build it on my raspberry pi and I don't understand the error.

When I build my app over my debian machine, everything build perfectly. Even if I get this line during the build process:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
```

Unfortunately, I cannot build  the same container on my raspberry. This warning get really worse and exit with error code 1:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcryp                                                                                                                                                             t.js/releases/download/v4.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v4.0.1-napi-v3-linux-arm-musl.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@4.0.1 and node@13.1.0                                                                                                                                                              (node-v79 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_mo                                                                                                                                                             dules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/no                                                                                                                                                             de_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/                                                                                                                                                             node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules                                                                                                                                                             /npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:314:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces                                                                                                                                                             s.js:270:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js                                                                                                                                                             :80:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.97-v7l+
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_mod                                                                                                                                                             ules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/app/                                                                                                                                                             node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_l                                                                                                                                                             ib" "--module_path=/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version                                                                                                                                                             =5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v13.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local                                                                                                                                                             /lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback                                                                                                                                                             -to-build --module=/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node                                                                                                                                                              --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi                                                                                                                                                             -v3 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_lab                                                                                                                                                             el=napi-v3' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-                                                                                                                                                             pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/chi                                                                                                                                                             ld_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.97-v7l+
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/.bin/node-pre                                                                                                                                                             -gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v13.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modu                                                                                                                                                             les/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/app/node_mo                                                                                                                                                             dules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --modu                                                                                                                                                             le_path=/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=5 --node_abi                                                                                                                                                             _napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm WARN clockmachine-api@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@4.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@4.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                                                                                                                                                             ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-26T14_29_34_636Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'backend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I don't understand this error code, because I have python, python2 and python3. Furthermore, if I type npm install node-pre-gyp it's working but not inside the container. I tried to clean npm cache and use with different nodejs version. the initial one, the 12.16.3 and the 14.x one.

Can you explain to me why this errors occurs ? What dependency should I fullfill and how to get the log inside the container?

Comment: can you please share your dockerFile ? also for node-gyp to run there must be python installed on the image

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? As my findings, it is because of ARM architecture of Raspberry Pie. Node-pre-gyp is having problem with it https://github.com/docker/getting-started/issues/124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't really need Node 13, maybe you can try using Node 8 (either using NVM or choosing the right Node Docker image).

This will skip building `bcrypt`.

(The reason you're even building `bcrypt` is because NPM "Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@4.0.1 and node@13.1.0")

Comment: This is exactly the point. I need bcrypt for my application to work. And it don't find the prebuilt binaries for bcrypt. I tried to install bcrypt with raspbian with both version of node (LTS and current) and it's working. The issue arise when I use a 64 bit OS like Ubuntu 20.04